# how to set up credentials for app google login and login to gmail

Tags: django, authentication, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

My (Django) app requires users to login using Google account. A feature of the app is also to send emails through Gmail API.

So far I have set up a credential of type `Web application` which works for login (last line).

[image]

The sending of email does not work with this ('Web app') credential because the step halts at

```
2016-09-09 05:30:53,535 :Starting new HTTPS connection (1): accounts.google.com
2016-09-09 05:30:53,779 :Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.googleapis.com
```

The above message makes me suspect that I have incorrect credentials. My question is:

Do I need to set two sets of credentials (and thus have two `client_secret.json` files) in google console, one for login and one for sending email through Gmail API? Or, do I peg login and Gmail-API authentication to one credential, by some mysterious magical chanting? Any info much appreciated.

Comment: Client id has access to all the APIs you have enabled in the enable api section.  As long as the user authenticates with the scopes email (I think that's the one or gmail) you can use the same client id for as many APIs as you like.  Its the scope of the authentication that decides what you can access.   The above message doesn't tell me much though.   Lets see a youtube video of the chanting :)

Comment: @DaImTo currently my only defined scope is [`'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes). I don't see (see previous link) where I could add "login" scope. Would like to see that youtube video myself. EDIT: Hum, maybe [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes), specifically `profile` and `login` under Google Sign-In?

Comment: Its been a while but I think login goes though plus https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth  btw gmail is a pain just saying and I am not a python person just trying to point you in the right direction

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks, I'll give it a whirl. The thing is working in development but somehow broke during deployment...

Comment: add code and ping me again if it doesn't work I can read python just not code it.  The client library's are all alike.

Comment: @DaImTo not a solution yet, but it would appear Django's [python-social-auth](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#multiple-scopes-per-provider) doesn't support multiple scopes by default. This may have been the root cause of why I can't auth with gmail API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding additional scopes in Django through `python-social-auth` is not out of the box, but is not hard either ([two ways described here](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/use_cases.html#multiple-scopes-per-provider)). I opted for the first option and overwrote the `get_scope` method.

In `views.py`, I set up

```
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
    scope=SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPES,
    redirect_uri='https://yourdomain.com/callbacklinkforgmail')
```

and the `redirect_uri` should match the redirected url in google console.

Requesting permission is done based on credentials stored somewhere. In my case, a model.

```
# model with variable/column 'credentials'
storage = Storage(YourModel, 'id', request.user, 'credentials')
            credential = storage.get()
            if credential is None or credential.invalid is True:
                flow.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY,
                                                               request.user)
                authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
            else:
                http = credential.authorize(httplib2.Http())
                service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```

When this step is done, redirect the `redirect_uri` to a function which confirms the match. In my case, this is in `views.py`.

```
@login_required
def auth_return(request):
    if not xsrfutil.validate_token(SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY, request.GET['state'].encode('utf-8'), request.user):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()

    credential = flow.step2_exchange(request.GET)
    storage = Storage(YourModel, 'id', request.user, 'credentials')
    storage.put(credential)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

and entry in `urls.py` of my app is

```
url(r'^callbacklinkforgmail/$', views.auth_return, name='mailsend')
```